# Django deployment with GTK3

Tags: django, deployment, gtk3, html-to-pdf

I have cretaed a django app, which uses weasyprint to convert html to pdf. This needed GTK3 to be installed on my local system. Now I'm not able to deploy on FL0. I checked the docs which said problems with deployment might be because the code couldn't be run properly. When I first used weasyprint, I was not able to run the app until I installed GTK3 on my laptop. So, I guess this is the issue. Is there any way to do this other than using docker. Or are there any libraries that does not use GTK3.
I'll provide any details required. If anyone needs.
Thanks.

I'm getting a CrashLoopBackoff error ( Back-off restarting failed ) on flow while deploying. It builds properly. But while deploying, I'm getting this error.

I have an option of containerizing the application. But I'm not able to do so at the moment for some other reasons. That's why I'm asking this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.